# Disable validation in xsd:anyType element

Tags: xml, validation, xsd

Having following XML Schema with a element of type `xs:anyType`.

```
<xs:schema xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" elementFormDefault="qualified">
    <xs:element name="root">
        <xs:complexType>
            <xs:sequence>
                <xs:element name="payloadAny" type="xs:anyType"/>                
            </xs:sequence>
        </xs:complexType>        
    </xs:element>
</xs:schema>
```

Any example of an XML:

```
<root xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
    <payloadAny>
        <anything>anyContent</anything>
    </payloadAny>
</root>
```

We now discovered the problem when in the  element is the **xsi:type** attribute like this:

```
<root xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
    <payloadAny>
        <anything xsi:type="ForeignType">anyContent</anything>
    </payloadAny>
</root>
```

This XML having the `xsi:type` attribute does not validate anymore against the XML Schema with the `xs:anyTyp`e element.

> E [Xerces] cvc-elt.4.2: Cannot resolve 'ForeignType' to a type definition for element 'anything'.

When using the `<xs:any/>` element instead of the `<element type="xs:anyType"/>`, the validation can be disabled using the *processContents* attribute.

```
<xs:schema xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" elementFormDefault="qualified">
    <xs:complexType name="any">
        <xs:sequence>
            <xs:any processContents="skip"/>
        </xs:sequence>
    </xs:complexType>      
    <xs:element name="root">
        <xs:complexType>
            <xs:sequence>
                <xs:element name="payloadAny" type="any"/>                
            </xs:sequence>
        </xs:complexType>        
    </xs:element>
</xs:schema>
```

The questions are now the following:

1. How to disable the `xsi:type` validation in a `xs:anyType` element (like `processContents="skip`)
2. Why is there such difference in a `<xs:any/>` vs. `<element type="xs:anyType"/>`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> How to disable the `xsi:type` validation in a `xs:anyType` element (like `processContents="skip"`)

With the element and type structure you have defined in your schema, the validation of the `xsi:type` attribute by the schema processor cannot be disabled.  A declaration for `xsi:type` is built in to every conforming XSD schema validator, and whenever an element with an `xsi:type` attribute is validated either strictly or laxly, that declaration will be found and the `xsi:type` attribute will be validated against it.  A valid `xsi:type` attribute has a QName value which identifies a type definition in the schema.  If the QName value does not identify a type definition, the attribute is invalid.

From the error message you are reporting, it appears that your schema contains no type whose expanded name is `{}ForeignType`.

One way to work around it would be to declare the type you appear to really want for the `payloadAny` element, which is not `xs:anyType` but a different type with a `skip` wildcard.  Your second schema example shows the principle, although your `{}any` type differs from `xs:anyType` in allowing only one element child, instead of allowing many elements and also character data. (If you only want one element as child of `payloadAny`, then `xs:anyType` is too loose.)

Note that the error reported is not a claim that the `anything` element is invalid against the type `ForeignType`, but a report that the `xsi:type` attribute is itself invalid, because it violates clause 4.2 of the constraint Element Locally Valid.  That in turn makes `payloadAny` invalid.

> Why is there such difference in a `<xs:any/>` vs. `<element type="xs:anyType"/>`

The built-in type `xs:anyType` behaves (roughly) as though declared with the following declaration shown in the XSD 1.0 schema for schema documents:

```
<xs:complexType name="anyType" mixed="true">
  <xs:annotation>
    <xs:documentation>
      Not the real urType, but as close an approximation as we can
      get in the XML representation</xs:documentation>
  </xs:annotation>
  <xs:sequence>
    <xs:any minOccurs="0" 
            maxOccurs="unbounded" 
            processContents="lax"/>
  </xs:sequence>
  <xs:anyAttribute processContents="lax"/>
```

There are no parameterization mechanisms for complex types analogous to the `processContents` and other attributes on `xs:any`.  Adding such mechanisms for `xs:anyType` would have required additional ad hoc mechanisms (is XSD not complicated enough for you?  you want more?) and would not have increased the expressive power of the language.

As design decisions go, that one looks pretty much like a no-brainer.   Even the XML Schema working group (never one to regard ad hoc machinery with much skepticism) thought such special-purpose machinery unnecessary.

In a schema language built on attribute grammars, where inherited attributes can serve to parameterize elements and/or types, such machinery would be a natural part of the language and having parameters for lax/strict/skip processing might make sense.  But neither XSD nor any other schema language in wide use is built on attribute grammars.